# Invalidation of Dependent Procedures in Oracle RPC Signature Dependency Mode on Data Type Change

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dependency-management

I'm working with Oracle's RPC Signature Dependency Mode and encountered unexpected behavior when changing a procedure's parameter data type within the same class. According to Oracle documentation, such changes shouldn't affect the RPC signature, yet it seems to invalidate dependent procedures. I'm hoping to gain some insights or solutions from the community.

Here's what I've done:

Set the session to signature dependency mode:

```
ALTER SESSION SET REMOTE_DEPENDENCIES_MODE = 'SIGNATURE';
```

Created a base procedure with a NUMBER parameter and a dependent procedure that calls this base procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE base_procedure (p_input IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    -- Procedure logic
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dependent_procedure IS
BEGIN
    base_procedure(1);  -- Calling the base procedure
    -- Additional logic
END;
```

Changed the base procedure's parameter from `NUMBER` to `FLOAT`, expecting no invalidation since they're in the same data type class:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE base_procedure (p_input IN FLOAT) IS
BEGIN
    -- Updated procedure logic
END;
```

After this change, the dependent procedure was invalidated, which contradicts my understanding of Oracle's documentation on signature dependency mode.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior or can provide clarity on why this invalidation occurs despite the data type change being within the same class? Any insights on how to manage such changes without causing invalidations would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It realy looks odd but you said it right in the question - the procedure was INVALIDATED (not INVALID as status says). It will be VALID again after first execution (suppose that is when validation happens - besides compile).

```sql
SELECT object_name, object_type, status FROM all_objects WHERE OBJECT_NAME IN('BASE_PROCEDURE', 'DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE');
--  no rows selected

ALTER SESSION SET REMOTE_DEPENDENCIES_MODE = 'SIGNATURE';
--  Session altered.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE base_procedure (p_input IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('base_procedure p_input = ' || p_input);
END;
--  Procedure BASE_PROCEDURE compiled

SELECT object_name, object_type, status FROM all_objects WHERE OBJECT_NAME IN('BASE_PROCEDURE', 'DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE');
--  OBJECT_NAME        OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS 
--  -----------------  ----------------------- -------
--  BASE_PROCEDURE     PROCEDURE               VALID 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dependent_procedure IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('dependent_procedure calling the base procedure NUMBER' );
    base_procedure(1); 
    -- Additional logic
END;
--  Procedure DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE compiled

SELECT object_name, object_type, status FROM all_objects WHERE OBJECT_NAME IN('BASE_PROCEDURE', 'DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE');
--  OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS 
--  -------------------  ----------------------- -------
--  BASE_PROCEDURE       PROCEDURE               VALID 
--  DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE  PROCEDURE               VALID
```

Changing base procedure results with "invalidity" of dependent:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE base_procedure (p_input IN FLOAT) IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('base_procedure FLOAT p_input = ' || p_input);
END;
--  Procedure BASE_PROCEDURE compiled

SELECT object_name, object_type, status FROM all_objects WHERE OBJECT_NAME IN('BASE_PROCEDURE', 'DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE');
--  OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS 
--  -------------------  ----------------------- -------
--  BASE_PROCEDURE       PROCEDURE               VALID 
--  DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE  PROCEDURE               INVALID
```

Now, if you run the procedure it will work just like expected (or compile it)....

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    dependent_procedure;
END;
/
--  dependent_procedure calling the base procedure NUMBER
--  base_procedure FLOAT p_input = 1
--  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

... and checking the status again - all is ok.

```sql
SELECT object_name, object_type, status FROM all_objects WHERE OBJECT_NAME IN('BASE_PROCEDURE', 'DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE');
--  OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS 
--  -------------------  ----------------------- -------
--  BASE_PROCEDURE       PROCEDURE               VALID 
--  DEPENDENT_PROCEDURE  PROCEDURE               VALID
```